# How can I change .rules file location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I specify a different location for the `.rules` file? I looked at .firebaserc, but can't find a proper property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of the `.rules` file is indicated in the `firebase.json` file. From the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#the_firebasejson_file):

> ```
> {
>   "hosting": {
>     "public": "public",
>     "ignore": [
>       "firebase.json",
>       "**/.*",
>       "**/node_modules/**"
>     ]
>   },
>   "firestore": {
>     "rules": "firestore.rules",
>     "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
>   },
>   "functions": {
>     "predeploy": [
>       "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```

So you can change the `/firestore/rules` property to set the location of the file.